# Running C Executable With Arguments As C Executable From Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I have written a shell script to run c executable with arguments.

```
`HOME=/home/visitor/
 PATH=.
 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Application/Exec/ShellScripts
 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Application/Exec/Utilities
 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Application/Exec/Run
 export PATH
 Resour >> $LOGDIR/log.Resour        //Resour is an exe
 SetLogLevel 6                       //SetLogLevel is an exe
 ExecCommand ProcessRealTime 1 1 ProcessRealTime >>$LOGDIR/log.ProcessRealTime  2>&1&`
```

However on running the above script , Resour and SetLogLevel exe are running properly but ExecCommand Exe which is used to start ProcessRealTime and make its entry in a shared memory shows **"execv: No such file or directory"**.

All my executable are under the path $HOME/Application/Exec/Run which has been exported.
But when I did the following changes , the script worked:

**ExecCommand $HOME/Application/Exec/RunProcessRealTime 1 1 ProcessRealTime >>$LOGDIR/log.ProcessRealTime  2>&1&**

Can someone help me in running the script without adding the paths and running the commands directly using just export statements.

Comment: How is this related to C? The fact that the executable was written in C does not mean the C tag is correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATH` environment variable affects the shell only. You have to implement your own path lookup if you use `execv` or move to `execvp` that does search the directories mentioned in the `PATH`